# Gradle setup to handle two deployment types with the same code base but different dependencies

Tags: java, gradle, dependencies, pom.xml

I'm working on a fresh web application project, which has to run in a distributed environment, as well as a good old "throw everything in a war file and run it on a tomcat"-environment.
The code is exactly the same for both versions, there is just a minor if/else clause to handle the different call types.

However, I'm struggling with the gradle setup now. I have two service, which we call "DAO" and "Connector" as an example. DAO uses Connector to retrieve data from a data source.
In the distributed mode, DAO has to depened on Connector:api, since DAO should only know said API, as the implementation runs somewhere else.
In the bundled mode, DAO has to depend on Connector:bundle, since all has to go into a single war-file.

All jars we produce are published on our internal nexus 3 server, using the maven-publish plugin. We're currently using gradle version 4.10.3, and the DAO project is part of a larger multi-project setup, of tightly coupled modules, while connector is a shared service to be used by another application.

To get these things done I've experimented with a number of ideas. Most of them were just plain wrong, so I won't bother talking about them here. What I now ended up with, is a multi-publish-setup.

```
  publishing {
    publications {
      dist(MavenPublication) {
        alias false
        from components.java
        afterEvaluate {
          artifact apiJar
        }
      }
      bundle(MavenPublication) {
        alias true
        from components.java
        afterEvaluate {
          artifactId "${artifactId}-bundle"
        }
      }
    }
    repositories {...}
}
```

This setup now generates 2 sets of pom- and jar-files. One for connector-api.jar and one for connector-bundle.jar

In the DAO dependency setup I now have to use if blocks to decide what dependency to setup:

```
gradle.taskGraph.whenReady { graph ->
    if (graph.hasTask(generatePomFileForBundlePublication)){
      dependencies {
        implementation "com.example:Connector-bundle:1.0.0"
      }
    }
    else {
      dependencies {
        implementation "com.example:Connector:1.0.0:api"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

However, this causes the issue that I do not have the library available at development time any longer. So I added the api-dependency unconditionally instead.

This does somewhat work, but now the generated pom-file ALWAYS has the api-dependency inside, and when I build the bundle version it has both dependencies.

So with this long explanation done, here is my question:
Are there any better ways of doing it instead of this... patchwork?
If not, can I at least deal with the dependency-duplication issue? When I'm building the bundled version, I do not wish to have the api-package. It is at best redundant, at worst it adds more redundant dependencies. I can't add it conditionally as I said above, because I lose the ability to develop against the API, and I don't want to manually add and remove it all the time.

Any help is appreciated, as I'm simply out of ideas.

PS: The usage of alias was to deal with the issue in the maven-publish plugin using multi-publishing in a multi-project environment (see https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/1061)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok after scrapping all my preconceptions and creating a gradle prototype I've found a working solution. This is what I've done:

First I've added a new property to gradle.properties **mode=dist**
This enabled me to split my dependencies via **if(mode == "dist")** and the **else** blocks. As an exmpale:

```
dependencies {
  if (mode == "dist"){
    implementation "com.example:Connector:1.0.0:api" 
  } else {
    implementation "com.example:Connector-bundle:1.0.0"
  }
}
```

Thanks to this setup, gradle by default now acts as if I'm in distribution mode, meaning I always load the API library, not the full thing.

Next I've created a custom task **publishBundle** where I set **mode = "lib"** and do the whole build and publish process. As an example:

```
task publishBundle {
  mode = "lib"
  dependsOn "build"
  dependsOn "publishBundlePublicationToNexusRepository"
}
```

The last adjustment had to happen in the publishing configuration. Here I had to add the correct mode values too:

```
  publishing {
    publications {
      dist(MavenPublication) {
        mode = "dist"
        alias false
        from components.java
        afterEvaluate {
          artifact apiJar
        }
      }
      bundle(MavenPublication) {
        mode = "lib"
        alias true
        from components.java
        afterEvaluate {
          artifactId "${artifactId}-bundle"
        }
      }
    }
    repositories {...}
  }
```

With this, the normal build and publish process will follow the distributed approach, while the **publishBundle** task creates and publishes the bundles. In our repository we now have two connector projects: connector and connector-bundle, meaning we can handle the different dependencies depending on the mode we're in.

It still feels like a patchwork, but I can imagine that my requirements are just too... special.